# calling environment and lapply

Tags: r, scope, environment, scoping

Below, I want `f()` to get information from its calling function.

```
f = function(x = NULL, env = parent.frame()) {
  print(str(as.list(env)))
}
```

I have another function `g()` to test that.

```
g = function() {
  y = TRUE
  f()
}
```

So far so good.

```
> y = FALSE
> g()
List of 1
 $ y: logi TRUE
NULL
```

But I also want `f()` to find `y` even if called from `lapply()`.

```
g2 = function(){
  y = TRUE
  lapply(1, f)
}
```

Because of how environments and lexical scoping work in R, the result is disappointing.

```
> g2()
List of 3
 $ i  : int 1
 $ X  : num 1
 $ FUN:function (x = NULL, env = parent.frame())  
  ..- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 5 3 1 5 1 1 3
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x105fc1a28> 
NULL
[[1]]
NULL
```

Is there a slick way to make `f()` find `y` automatically in both cases, or am I stuck with having to manually passing the environment?

```
g3 = function(){
  y = TRUE
  lapply(1, f, env = environment())
}

> g3()
List of 1
 $ y: logi TRUE
NULL
[[1]]
NULL
```

Comment: You seem to be doing a bunch of weird shit with NSE, given your question history. There's probably a much easier way of doing what you want to do. Nevertheless, check out the lazyeval package which seems to address this specific question nicely.

Comment: Which part of lazyeval specifically? I read through the vignettes, and I feel like I'm missing your point.

Comment: `g3` seems the way to go but you could define a variation of `lapply` that passes `env` and then use that instead of `lapply` in your function. `lapply.env <- function(..., env = parent.frame()) lapply(..., env = env)`